# serialize a tuple of strings in play framework application

Tags: ajax, playframework

I am new in scala programming.
I want to know how tell play to serialize a tuple of strings.

Thanks in advance

Lotfi

Comment: I mean : how to tell play to serialize a tuple of strings in json format. for more détail: serilaze this seq[(String,String)] to json format.

Comment: But what should that logically serialize to in JSON? There is no tuple analog in JSON. Should it be an array? Should `Seq[(String, String)]` be an array of arrays? These details are important to include in your question, because they are not obvious.

Answer (score 0):

If it's to get a Json object from a Seq[(String,String)]:

```
 val seq = Seq[(String,String)](("attr1"->"val1"),("attr2"->"val2"))
 val s = Json.toJson(seq.map(e => Json.obj((e._1 -> e._2))))
 Ok(s).as(JSON)
```